# What are the limitations of using Wolfram cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, scripting

I have a program which requires more than 2 hours of running on my computer. I tried to use Wolfram cloud to run the script, but after few lines on evaluation and reaching the time consuming part, the evaluation stopped and needed to run again.

Is this a bug or just a limitation of computation? And what are the limitation of using Wolfram cloud?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. As the site banner suggests, this stack site is about the technical computing software called Mathematica and the associated Wolfram Language. Questions regarding other Wolfram technologies such as the `Cloud` are considered to be off-topic. You can post this over at the [community](https://community.wolfram.com/) website. Thanks.